# ParseQuery NullPointer Fetch data from back4app server

Tags: android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

While trying to retrieve information from Parse such as string
i have received error
at itemadapter.addall()give me error

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery<>("MyPhoto");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    itemAdapter.clear();
                    itemAdapter.addAll(objects);
                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Items.this,"Error: " + e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

this is my adapter class

```
{
private Context context;
    private List<ParseObject> objects;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context,List<ParseObject>list){
        super(context, R.layout.items,list);
        this.context=context;
        objects=list;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
        TextView textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items);
        ParseObject myPhoto=objects.get(position);
        textView.setText(myPhoto.getString("Name"));
        return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You've failed to provide a logcat in your question

Comment: Can you please paste here the stack trace of the error you have?

Comment: thanks for your replay but now i solve my error